# What is difference between meta-data and resource?

Tags: android

I have found good explanation about the [meta-data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html). But I'm confused about `resource` and `meta-data`. We declare the `meta-data` for storing the information statically but we also use the `resource` to store the information statically. Here is the example.

```
<meta-data android:name="my_test_metagadata" android:value="testValue" />
```

Here is the resource example

```
<resource>
<string name="my_test_resourcedata">value</a>
</resource>
```

We can access the both data in code. Then what is special in the `meta-data`?

Comment: That page explains the difference... Read at *"to assign a resource ID as the value, use the resource attribute instead"*

Comment: that is the difference between `android:resource` and `android:value` of `meta-data` tag.

Comment: Ah yes. Well, the metadata is only accessible as a manifest tag and there are other resources than just strings https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 3):

[`meta-data`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html) is located in the Manifest and therefore is accessible to the Android system and other components like 3rd party SDKs you might be using. For this reason `meta-data` is used to store data you need to expose to 3ed party components in your application. [Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) on the other hand are private to your application and used to enable your application to adopt to different circumstances such as language,orientation,etc.

Comment: how we can access it from outside of application? any example?

Comment: You can see an example here :http://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/10/08/using-meta-data-in-an-androidmanifest/

Comment: Can't you access resources of other apps as well? The full syntax is `[<package_name>.]R.<resource_type>.<resource_name>`

Comment: No. Only other app components. You can expose things like content providers or handling intents from other apps through the mainfest but it isn't done through the `meta-data`.

Comment: @SirCodesalot I think that code is only for within the application not outside of the application mean the other application than yours own.

Comment: I understand that my answer wasn't clear enough. In "expose" I meant to 3ed party components **inside your application**. Edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: @SirCodesalot I think the 3rd party component should be able to access the resources too. If not any official documentation about this? that is showing 3rd party SDKs can't access resources?

Comment: @UnKnown since accessing resources is done by ID in the R file of the application which is unavailable to the SDK at compile time, you can't do it. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html